# How to change the style of CComboBox scrollbar in MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I want to change the style of scrollbar of `CComboBox`. I can only change the selected item and background of dropbox, but haven't found any way to change the default style of scrollbar.

And is there any way to get the index of the current item shown on dropbox, so that I can draw my own scrollbar?

Comment: You should be able to use `GetCurSel` to get the currently selected index.

Comment: after `GetCurSel` how to redraw the scrollbar of CComboBox?

Comment: The answer to that is not easy. Most likely ownerdraw the complete control.

Comment: What kind of style customization for your combo-box's scroll-bar do you want to achieve exactly? Very few customization options here, if you don't make a completely owner-drawn control as noted, which btw is a non-trivial job.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou I just want to hide the top& bottom button of the scrollbar, and make it thinner, hide the background and only show the thumb

Comment: This also depends on the theme you have currently selected. Perhaps you will need to override the theme (`CMFCVisualManager`) with you own and style the things you want You also have to select that theme instead (`CMFCVisualManager::SetDefaultManager` )

Comment: I would suggest you to investigate how the themes that already come with the framework are working, all of them are descendant classes of `CMFCVisualManager ` One example here: [CMFCVisualManagerOfficeXP Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcvisualmanagerofficexp-class)